# How did Mama and Papa bear know someone was sitting in their chairs?

Tags: folk-tales

Goldilocks sits in Mama and Papa bears' chairs, but does not break them:

> After she'd eaten the three bears' breakfasts she decided she was feeling a little tired.  So, she walked into the living room where she saw three chairs.  Goldilocks sat in the first chair to rest her feet.
>
> "This chair is too big!" she exclaimed.
>
> So she sat in the second chair.
>
> "This chair is too big, too!"  she whined.

Later, when the bears come home, they somehow discover someone had been sitting in the chairs:

> "Someone's been sitting in my chair," growled the Papa bear.
>
> "Someone's been sitting in my chair," said the Mama bear.

What did Mama and Papa bear see that led them to believe someone had been sitting in their chairs?

Comment: Maybe it wasn't anything they saw. ["Bears are thought to have the best sense of smell of any animal on earth."](https://sectionhiker.com/bears_sense_of_smell/)

Comment: I always wondered why the smallest bowl of porridge was still warm, when the middle-size bowl was cold.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the 1839 [edition](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Story_of_the_Three_Bears_(1839)) of Robert Southey's *The Story of the Three Bears* it was because their chairs' cushions were disturbed:

> "Somebody in my chair has sat!"
>   With voice so gruff and great
>   The Huge bear said, when he saw that
>   His cushion was not straight.
>
> "Somebody in my chair has been!"
>   The middle Bear exclaim'd;
>   Seeing the cushion dinted in
>   By what may not be named.

The wording was slightly different in the [first edition](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=yul.11369938_004_00;view=1up;seq=357) (of 1837). The history of this story (and its publication history)  is interesting and complex: see the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldilocks_and_the_Three_Bears) on it. In particular, the identity of the home invader has changed.

Comment: This is very cool. I wonder why this connection was left out of later versions.

Comment: I dunno.  I suppose if you are telling the story, the tension mounts, the rhythm of the story infects the listeners, and at the chair stage of the narrative an explanation of *why* the first 2 bears noticed the disturbance might seem to the narrator like a distraction.  The audience perhaps identifies with the youngest bear, the main victim of the home invasion, and doesn't care about the elder bears' ratiocinations.

Answer (score 1):

The chairs were disorganized and put in an unorderly fashion, suggesting that they had recently moved, along with the seat cushions (as stated in the other answer).